# Question about ramification groups

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

This is part a of question 22 of chapter 4 in Marcus' *Number Fields*, and is also not homework. Let $K$ be a number field and let $L$ be a normal extension of $K$. Let $\mathcal{O}_K$ and $\mathcal{O}_L$ denote the rings of integers in $K$ and $L$ respectively. Let $P \subseteq \mathcal{O}_K$ be a prime ideal and let $Q \subseteq \mathcal{O}_L$ be a prime of $L$ lying over $P$. Let $E(Q|P)$ denote the inertia group of $G = Gal(L/K)$, that is

$E(Q|P) = \{ \sigma \in G : \sigma(x) \equiv x \pmod{Q} \mbox{  for all  } x \in \mathcal{O}_L\}.$

For $m \geq 0$, define the ramification groups $V_m$ as

$V_m = \{\sigma \in G : \sigma(x) \equiv x \pmod{Q^{m+1}} \mbox{  for all  }\mathcal{O}_L\}.$

The question is as follows: Fix $\pi \in Q \setminus Q^2$. For each $\sigma \in V_{m-1}$ prove that there exists $\alpha \in \mathcal{O}_L$, depending on $\sigma$, such that

$\sigma(\pi) \equiv \pi + \alpha \pi^m \pmod{Q^{m+1}}$

where $\alpha$ is uniquely determined mod $Q$.

I thought I had an idea of how to do this but I keep getting stuck. My argument is this. Since $\pi \in Q \setminus Q^2$, then $\pi^m \in Q^m \setminus Q^{m+1}$ for all $m \geq 1$. Write $\pi\mathcal{O}_L = Q I$ where $I \subseteq \mathcal{O}_L$ is an ideal that is not divisible by $Q$. Then the Chinese Remainder Theorem implies that there exists an element $x \in \mathcal{O}_L$ that is unique modulo $Q^{m+1}I^m$ that satisfies $x \equiv \sigma(\pi) \pmod{Q^{m+1}}$ and $x \equiv 0 \pmod{I^m}.$ Now using this, and the fact that $\sigma(\pi) \equiv \pi \pmod{Q^m}$, one gets that $x - \pi \in Q^i$ for all $i \in \{1, \ldots, m\}$. Since $\pi \in Q$, we get that $x \in Q$ as well so that $x \in QI^m = (\pi\mathcal{O}_L)I^{m-1}$ (its in the intersection of the two ideals, hence the product as they are relatively prime) so that $x = \pi a$ where $a \in I^{m-1}$. Then we get $\pi(a-1) \in Q^m$, which implies that $a-1 \in Q^{m-1}$. This is where I am stuck and just keep going in circles. Clearly we can't have $a-1 \in I^{m-1}$, which is what we want, because then $1 \in I^{m-1}$. I think this is probably not very difficult and I'm overlooking something easy but I haven't been able to see it. Any help, or even a hint would be much appreciated.

Edit: I should note that this is Claim 5.23 in Mollin's *Algebraic Number Theory*, however I think the proof is incorrect. He fixes $\pi \in Q \setminus Q^2$, and then proceeds to write $\pi\mathcal{O}_L = Q^mI$ where $q \nmid I$, which is not correct as $Q^2 \nmid \pi\mathcal{O}_L.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since
$$\text{GCD}(\pi^m \mathcal{O}_L,\; Q^{m+1}) = Q^m,$$
we have
$$Q^m = \pi^m \mathcal{O}_L + Q^{m+1}.$$
Perhaps this helps.

Comment: I knew it was going to be simple. Thank you.